# prestashop This page is not available

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am getting below error on each places rather then homepage. I mean when I am trying to access order page its throwing me this error:

This page is not available

We're sorry, but the Web address you've entered is no longer available.

To find a product, please type its name in the field below.

---

I tried to regenerate htaccess file but still error there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .htaccess file (backup it!) Then go to backoffice and regenerate .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Please activate the errors like this :

```
Goto in your FTP folder  /config/
Open config.inc.php
Change line (set "on") 29 :
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on')

Open defines.inc.php
change set "true":
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

Go to home page and tell us the error.

Comment: I am using latest prestashop and I asked as you said but it seems there are nothing like this "ini_set('display_errors', 'on')". and define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true) is already set.

Answer (score 0):

what web server you use, if you use the apache you can adding this code in httpd.conf

```
<Directory "D:/htdocs/master">
     All Options
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow, deny
     Allow from all
</ Directory>
```

edit according to your condition